# Difference between process and concurrent statements

Tags: concurrency, process, signals, vhdl

when I assign Signal F the complement of Signal B in a process like this:

```
architecture V1 of E is 
 signal B: bit; 
begin 
 process (A) begin 
  B<=A; 
  F<=not b; 
 end process; 
end architecture;
```

then F will hold the old negated value of B in the first cycle.

But why doesn't the same hold for this example where I'm just using concurrent statements?

```
architecture V1 of E is 
 signal B : bit; 
begin 
  B<=A; 
  F<=not b; 
end architecture;
```

When I'm thinking of the Hardware components F will receive the signal from B so in the first cycle F should also hold the old negated value of B?

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 11.6 Concurrent signal assignment statements "A concurrent signal assignment statement represents an equivalent process statement that assigns values to signals." *...so in the first cycle F should...* 11. Concurrent statements 11.1 General "Within a given simulation cycle, an implementation may execute concurrent statements in parallel or in some order. The language does not define the order, if any, in which such statements will be executed. ...." You don't specify which of your two snippets. Provide a [mcve] with a single specific programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concurrent signal assignments are just shorthand for processes. Your second code is the same as:

```vhdl
process(A)
begin
  B <= A;
end process;

process(b)
begin
  F <= not b;
end process;
```

The reason why the behavior differs is that with your first code the process resumes only when signal `A` changes while with the second each process resumes each time the signal in its sensitivity list changes.